# Using the automatic connect slots by name

Tags: python, signals-slots, pyside2

A while ago, I had been using (in a given framework at work) the automatic connect slots by name feature in Qt4, with a decorator. Something like this:

```
self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
...
@QtCore.Slot()
def on_button1_clicked(self):
     # whatever the method does...
```

instead of this:

```
self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
self.button1.clicked.connect(self.handle_button)
...
def self.handle_button(self):
    # whatever the method does...
```

Now I am not able to make it work with PySide2 (Qt-5.12). What I am missing here to make it work?

```
import sys
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "Hola Mundo"]

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

        #self.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_button1_clicked)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_button1_clicked(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)`.

Comment: Could you please be more precise? What I am doing wrong in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connectSlotsByName` feature is usually used with Qt Designer files. When those files are converted with the `uic` tool, a lot of boiler-plate code gets added. This includes setting the object-name, which is required when connecting slots by name:

```
self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
self.button1.setObjectName('button1')
```

Obviously, the object-name must match the name used in the slot.

Comment: I must admit that I was using all the time with the Qt Designer files. I thought that there could be a possibility to use it anyway. Doesn't matter, is just few lines more to use it as usual. Thanks!!

Comment: Just trying to saving lines, and at the end, there is one more... Doesn't worth it, I guess... but I am happy to know how it works.